# How can I use function template_preprocess_field() to pass a value from one field to an attribute of another field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I have an **Entity Product entity** where one of the fields is:

- reference field on Media type with name **Media Product Image**

Media Product Image has fields:

- Image
- Custom color id

And in the developers tools of the browser, the `<img>` looks like this:

```
<img loading="lazy src="/sites/default/files/styles...." width="300" height="550" typeof=foaf:Image>
```

I need to add the `data-color` attribute to the `<img>` tag and pass the value from the **Custom Color id** field to it.
This can be done with:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/9.4.x

For example:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_image') {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is that when I write the word `media` in the **.module** file in my **entity_product_admin** module in the function name:

```
function entity_product_admin_preprocess_media(&$variables, $hook) {
}
```

I can't get the value of **field_custom_color_id** because there is no method in the API of the **media** entity with which I can get the value of this field:

[image]

Also, I don't have access to the image attributes and I can't add the `data-color` attribute with the value of the **Custom color id** field.

If I write the word `image` in the name of the function:

```
function entity_product_admin_preprocess_image(&$variables, $hook) {
}
```

Then I already have access to the image attributes, but I do not have access to the **field_custom_color_id** field:
[image]

I tried to write just **field** in the function name, but then I can get through anywhere.
How then should this function look like?

Comment: This question has been already asked on a different Stack Exchange site (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312313/how-can-i-use-function-template-preprocess-field-to-pass-a-value-from-one-fiel), four minutes before being asked here.