# How to correctly render this media element?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I have an entity that has a reference field on the Media Type. I take the reference field on Media Type to display images:

```
$storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
$entity_product = $storage->load($entity_id);
$entity_product_media_ids = $entity_product->get('field_entity_product_media')->getValue();
```

And as a result, the `$entity_product_media_ids` variable contains:

[image]

Comment: Asking the same question 3 times... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144595) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312313) is not a good idea, Especially when this question has fewer details than the others.

Comment: You have the IDs of the Media entities, send all the IDs as an array to [loadMultiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/function/EntityBase%3A%3AloadMultiple/9.3.x)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use function template\_preprocess\_field() to pass a value from one field to an attribute of another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144595/how-can-i-use-function-template-preprocess-field-to-pass-a-value-from-one-fiel)